# Salesforce application - table xpath not working

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver, salesforce

This is a Salesforce application, I want to collect a value from table (datatable), below is the HTML code

```
<table class="slds-table forceRecordLayout slds-table--header-fixed slds-table--edit slds-table--bordered resizable-cols slds-table--resizable-cols uiVirtualDataTable" data-aura-rendered-by="519:0" data-aura-class="uiVirtualDataTable" style="width: 1256px;">
<thead data-aura-rendered-by="520:0">
<tfoot data-aura-rendered-by="523:0"></tfoot>
<tbody data-aura-rendered-by="524:0">
<tr>
<td class="slds-cell-edit slds-cell-edit slds-cell-error errorColumn cellContainer" tabindex="-1" data-aura-rendered-by="809:0">
<td class="slds-cell-edit cellContainer" tabindex="-1" data-aura-rendered-by="833:0">
<th class="slds-cell-edit cellContainer" scope="row" tabindex="-1" data-aura-class="forceInlineEditCell" data-aura-rendered-by="850:0">
<span class="slds-grid slds-grid--align-spread forceInlineEditCell" data-aura-rendered-by="866:0" data-aura-class="forceInlineEditCell">
<a class="slds-truncate outputLookupLink slds-truncate forceOutputLookup" data-refid="recordId" data-recordid="a2F46000000Y3s0EAC"
 data-special-link="true" href="#/sObject/a2F46000000Y3s0EAC/view" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" title="QE"
 data-aura-rendered-by="860:0" data-aura-class="forceOutputLookup">QE</a>
<span class="triggerContainer" data-aura-rendered-by="868:0">
</span>
</th>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to scrape the `QE` value from the table it's located in the first row.

Below is my xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='slds-table forceRecordLayout slds-table--header-fixed slds-table--edit slds-table--bordered\n" +
" resizable-cols slds-table--resizable-cols uiVirtualDataTable']/tbody/tr/th/span")).getText();
```

Using the table class name to frame this xpath, but I am getting `Unable to locate element`

Error description:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//table[@class='slds-table forceRecordLayout slds-table--header-fixed slds-table--edit slds-table--bordered
 resizable-cols slds-table--resizable-cols uiVirtualDataTable']/tbody/tr/th/span"}
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 300.01 seconds
```

Note: When i execute my xpath in FirePath , its finding correctly, but while executing its not finding

Comment: Can you update the question with the complete error stack trace?

Comment: @DebanjanB : added in my question

Answer (score 0):

As you are working with **`chromedriver=2.29`** as per the Release Notes **`chromedriver=2.29`** supports **`Supports Chrome v56-58`**. So as we are working with **`chrome=61.0`** we need to upgrade the  **`chromedriver`** binary to minimum **`v2.32`**.

Next, to scrape the text **`QE`** value from the table you can use the following code block :

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//th[@class='slds-cell-edit cellContainer']/span/a[@class='slds-truncate outputLookupLink slds-truncate forceOutputLookup']")).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
```

Comment: Thanks for information about chromedriver but text scrape getting same exception Unable to locate element,